# What's the best way to provide forgotten password functionality with CouchDB and Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, couchdb

I've got an ajax app built using backbone.js and it's hooked up to a couchdb instance. I am trying to build forgotten password functionality using the following workflow:

1) user enters their username
2) I send them an email with a link in it
3) the user accesses the link and enters a new password

I can't figure out how to actually get the password updated however. For security reasons, I'm not going to embed admin creds into the client, and it looks to me like a user has to be authenticated before they can make changes to their password.

Thank you for your time and assistance. Hopefully I'm just overlooking something silly.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this: save a unique key to DB, send a link that includes that key to visitor email and of course when he will access the link you will need to check the availability of that key, maybe consider 15 minutes since key was sent or decline his reset request

Comment: Yes, the links not the issue, the issue is changing the password. Thank you!